# Soap api insert data request does not work in Java

Tags: java, xml, api, soap

I have to use SOAP api for a small project. I can retrieve data now, but as I try to insert data it won't seem to work and gives me this error: **Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I am using the following soap resource for the post-request: http://webapp.tcscourier.com/codapi/Service1.asmx?op=InsertData

I have the following code:

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/xml");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\r\n  <soap12:Body>\r\n    <InsertData xmlns=\"http://202.61.51.93:6265/\">\r\n      <userName>string</userName>\r\n      <password>string</password>\r\n      <costCenterCode>string</costCenterCode>\r\n      <consigneeName>string</consigneeName>\r\n      <consigneeAddress>string</consigneeAddress>\r\n      <consigneeMobNo>string</consigneeMobNo>\r\n      <consigneeEmail>string</consigneeEmail>\r\n      <originCityName>string</originCityName>\r\n      <destinationCityName>string</destinationCityName>\r\n      <pieces>string</pieces>\r\n      <weight>string</weight>\r\n      <codAmount>0.2</codAmount>\r\n      <custRefNo>string</custRefNo>\r\n      <productDetails>string</productDetails>\r\n      <fragile>string</fragile>\r\n      <services>string</services>\r\n      <remarks>string</remarks>\r\n      <insuranceValue>string</insuranceValue>\r\n    </InsertData>\r\n  </soap12:Body>\r\n</soap12:Envelope>");
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://webapp.tcscourier.com/codapi/Service1.asmx?op=InsertData")
            .method("POST", body)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(response.body().string());
        System.out.println(xmlJSONObj.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add SoapAction Header in request.

addHeader("soapaction", "http://202.61.51.93:6265/InsertData")

Comment: There must be some sort of internal requirement that we cannot know without knowing it. I have tried it with another web service and it does work. I suggest anyone looking for clarification on SOAP to look into Postman and then afterwards moving to Java. A valuable resource for me was the following link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xC4QQCQDDDk